# GWT : A widget that has an existing parent widget may not be added to the detach list

Tags: gwt

This code in GWT (Sidebar is a custom that build a sidear) :

```
HTML html = new HTML("
                 <div id=\"container\">some stuff</div>"
        );

RootPanel.get("container").add(new Sidebar());
```

... give that error :

```
java.lang.AssertionError: A widget that has an existing parent widget may not be added to the detach     list
at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel.detachOnWindowClose(RootPanel.java:136)
at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel.get(RootPanel.java:211)
```

Can you helpplease. I have seen many explanations but nothing help me.

thanks      +

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I won't delve into explanations, as you say you read them already: enough to say this is an unsupported pattern.

In your case, you'll want to use an `HTMLPanel` instead of `HTML` widget, and use the `HTMLPanel`'s `add(Widget,String)` method to put the `Sidebar` into the `container` element:

```
HTMLPanel html = new HTMLPanel("<div id='container'>some stuff</div>");
html.add(new Sidebar(), "container");
```

Comment: Thank you thomas !! It just works well. Can you give some explanations why it isn't a unsupported pattern ?

Comment: ...And when we want to remove the sidebar otherwise ?